# Jquery put element inside another not after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I have a few images and some element which I can drag and drop on images

```
<span name="imie" id="drag1" class="drag">
    <img name='aa' id='test' src="http://placehold.it/80x80/c9112d/fff&text=1" width="70px" height="20px" />
    </span>
    <span>Imię</span> 

<div class="col droppable">
    <div class="canvas">
        <img class="img-bg" src="test.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="canvas">
        <img class="img-bg" src="test.jpg">
    </div>                    
</div>
```

I want to add dropped box inside `<div class="canvas">` after or before `img`. I want to see that box is on img but in code it should be inside `canvas` not after 
This is my script

```
 var counter = 0;
        var x = null;
        //Make element draggable
        $(".drag").draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            cursor: 'move',
            tolerance: 'fit',
            revert: true
        });

        $(".droppable").droppable({
            accept: '.drag',
            activeClass: "drop-area",
            drop: function (e, ui) {
                if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id !== "") {


                    x = ui.helper.clone();
                    ui.helper.remove();
                    x.draggable({
                        helper: 'original',
                        cursor: 'move',
                        containment: '.droppable',
                        tolerance: 'fit',
                        drop: function (event, ui) {
                            $(ui.draggable).remove();
                        }
                    });


                    x.addClass('remove');

                    var el = $("<span><a href='Javascript:void(0)' class='xicon delete'                  title='Remove'</a>X</span>");
                    $(el).insertAfter($(x.find('img')));
                    x.appendTo('.droppable');
                    $('.delete').on('click', function () {
                        $(this).parent().parent('span').remove();
                    });
                    $('.delete').parent().parent('span').dblclick(function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

I suppose that problem is in              `x.appendTo('.droppable');` . But I can't handle with it.
And whole example online [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/D3BF3/)

Comment: You have two `<div class="canvas">`, which one should it be added to?

Comment: @Barmar I want to added to currently dropped canvas

Comment: The canvases aren't droppable, only the DIV containint them is. I don't see a way in the Droppable API to find out which sub-element you're over when you drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your `<div class="canvas"></div>` droppable not the `<div class="col droppable"></div>`

Try:

HTML:

```
<div class="col ">
    <div class="canvas droppable">
        <img class="img-bg" src="http://formularze.iform.pl/zdjecia/formularze/4556/SF_sdfra.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="canvas droppable">
        <img class="img-bg" src="http://formularze.iform.pl/zdjecia/formularze/4556/SF_sdfra.gif">
    </div>                    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(this).append(x);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D3BF3/6/)

Or if you want it before the `img` Try:

```
$(this).prepend(x);
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/D3BF3/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for for `append`

```
$( ".canvas" ).append( "<p>whateva</p>" );
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: It add to the last images not first